# Google AdMob Ads SDK only works in simulator

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator, admob

SDK version 5.0.4, device has IOS 4.3.2. When building for the simulator, all is fine and the ads load. When changing to 'device', I get 9000+ warnings(!) "unexpected srelocation type 9" when linking the app itself. When run on a device, the app crashes (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) at the first call in viewDidLoad, `[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame]`.

The problem we had was that originally, we used AdWhirl to serve the old AdMob (nee Google Admob) ads. When using the proper non-test AdWhirl account, AdMob ads (only!) would never show up.

I've tried updating AdWhirl and Google Admob in one go, and removing AdWhirl only using the new AdMob. With the latter the behavior is as described above, when used with AdWhirl it crashes a few seconds later when AdWhirl has loaded the ad.

Surely someone else got this, what did you do to solve it?

(Update: on installing it on another Iphone, I strangely got more info than EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It says:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries.)
Cannot access memory at address 0x2fdfe8c0
Cannot access memory at address 0x2fdfe8c0
```

My guess then is that I must make a shared library static (and that it works on the Simulator, because it has dlopen()). How do I do that?
)

Comment: hi can you send adsupport library for xcode 4.3.3, i am using this xcode but there in not any library of such type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that that with SDK Version 5.0.4, it will only work if you are on the latest version of XCode which is I believe 4.2. Are you on the latest version of XCode?

Comment: From the readme: This is the Google AdMob Ads SDK for iOS.

Requirements:
- An AdMob site ID, AdSense client ID, or DoubleClick for Publishers account
- Xcode 3.2 or later.
- Runtime of iOS 3.0 or later.

Comment: I meant to add that I'm not using the latest version of XCode but fulfill the requirements. :) Did you write this as answer because you know it helped you with this problem? I have a hard time believing that (mainly because it doesn't crash in simulator, which is the primary clue to me).

Comment: Saw a similar issue on the AdMob Google Groups forum, and it seemed to fix the persons issue there.

Comment: I'd ask you to see if you could find the thread on Google Groups, but I'm not a sadistic person. :p I've downloaded the latest XCode, will give it a shot.

Comment: I can hereby confirm 100% that updating XCode to 4.2 solves the problem completely, that there's no way to make it work on the XCode version in the requirements doc from Google, and that it's the only change required. (Apart from installing the latest Google AdMob SDK and optionally the latest AdWhirl SDK correctly, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the framework `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` from `GoogleAdMob SDK`.

Use previous version of `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` from adMob.com for your `Xcode`, not the new one.

After that all 11345 warnings gone and app runs correct on device.

Regards, Papa Buba